# What is the best way and what work is involved in fixing this wheel stud?

Tags: hub, stud, assembly

I have damaged wheel studs on a hub and want to replace them.  Initially I thought I could just hammer the studs out press new ones in however from the pics you can see that the studs are too close to the back component, if you try to hammer it a little it will hit the back part out and you will not be able to maneuver it out, my mechanic also said this. This is the case even if you rotate the hub.

It seems to me my options are to:

a) dissamble the hub and put the studs in.  However I cannot see any nuts or bolts to undo which will remove the back parts.  This being the case, what would I have to do to remove the parts in order to press the new studs in?

b) buy a new hub and put that in however once again I cannot see any way to undo the current assembly i.e. no nuts or bolts will let me dissasemble it.

c) by the complete assembly(i.e. second hand) and just put that in. In this case I think i'd just have to put the axle through the middle and then just connect the top and bottom ends.  What does this entail because I think I can see a ball joint at the bottom so is there a special way to connect that part?

Please answer above questions and tell me, in order which is the easiest and probably least costly methods to use.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the car?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 honda civic vti em1 1999 manual.  In the us I think it's referred to as the civic si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first two photos, the assembly with the studs has to be pressed out of the carrier assembly.

To do this you will need a decent hydraulic (or screw - but they are not too common as the pressure required can be high) press.

So, you will need to take it to a garage or shop for them to press it out and then they can also press out the old studs and press in the new.

Be warned, it should not cause any damage to the bearing, but sometimes it is worth fitting a new one anyway...

Comment: Would it be easier and cheaper to just put a used assembly in.  I imagine its just a case of putting the driveshaft through, clicking the ball joint in and nutting them joins down?  Is it really the simple or is there more to it?

Comment: You have no idea of how long a “used” unit will last - so you could end up doing the job twice very quickly, but I gave you good info - how you want to spend /waste your money is up to you..