# How to know if bearing is damaged in my case?

Tags: wheel-bearing, stud

I'm about to get some wheel studs replaced and this requires the wheel bearing to be pressed out first as you cannot really access the studs without removing the bearing.

My mechanic said he might not have to use a new bearing since if the old one doesn't break then its not damaged.  Is this correct?  I was under the impression that even if the old one doesnt break it could get damaged or is that only the case if you hammer the studs without pressing out the bearing first?

This work has come about from a wheel coming off due to broken studs.  I'm thinking to change all studs on all wheels.  Could it be the case that when the corner of the car fell to the ground, bearing on all wheels also damaged?  My mechanic doesnt know the background of what happened, but if the fall could damage all bearings might it be best to change all bearings?

Comment: You asked the same thing here and it was answered: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/58159/10976

Comment: @SolarMike no, they are different questions.  The linked question is asking how to disassemble the hub.  This question is asking whether a bearing could be damaged by the car falling to the ground and if it doesn't break during removal, does this mean it is still working as mechanic stated.  He is the one insisting he will keep it if it doesnt brake though I do agree you may as well put a new bearing in there, though that doesnt mean the old is damaged.

Comment: I answered your question in paragraph 2 in my answer....

Comment: You have answered that one may not know how long a used bearing will last so its best to replace it (with which I agree) and that the pressing of a bearing in and of itself should not damage a bearing.  However this question is asking a) can a car falling to the ground damage the bearings and b) if a bearing is ALREADY damaged will it break at point of being taken out(I'm assuming it can be taken out, not break and still be damaged) so the way to know if its damaged is if there are other symptoms when driving, however my mechanics seems to have said it its damagedin any way it will break.